# Java: Updating variable from other class

Tags: java, class, variables, graphics

I'm struggling with a strange issue that I cannot seem to solve.. I used various methods (like setting the variable directly by shape.rightident = 1, etc..)

Class:

```
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;

public abstract class MyShape {

protected int rightidentifier = -1; // to make sure you get an error when it is not being changed.
protected int x1, y1, x2, y2;
protected int width, height, startx, starty;

public MyShape() {
    this(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

public MyShape(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {
    this.x1 = x1;
    this.x2 = x2;
    this.y1 = y1;
    this.y2 = y2;
}


public void setRightIdent(int identt) {
    this.rightidentifier = identt;
}

public int getRightIdent() {
    return this.rightidentifier;
}
}
```

Now when I try to set the variable:

```
public void addToShapeList(MyShape shape) {
    int currcount;
    switch(shape.type) {
        case "Rectangle":
            rectanglecount++;
            currcount = rectanglecount;
            break;
        case "Line":
            linecount++;
            currcount = linecount;
            break;
        case "Ellipse":
            ellipsecount++;
            currcount = ellipsecount;
            break;
        default:
            currcount = 0;
            break;
    }
    listModel.addElement(shape.type + " " + currcount);
    shape.rightidentifier = listModel.size() - 1;
    shape.setRightIdent(listModel.size()-1);
    System.out.println("setted rightident to " + (listModel.size() -1));
    System.out.println("Rightident now:" + shape.getRightIdent());
}

public void deleteFromList(MyShape shape) {
    System.out.println("tried to remove rightident: " + shape.getRightIdent());
    listModel.remove(shape.getRightIdent());

}
```

Then the system output:

```
setted rightident to 0
Rightident now:0
tried to remove rightident: -1
```

It seems like the object doesn't save the updated variable, what can I do to save the variable?

Edit: full code: https://github.com/Rubenkl/peent-daanruben/tree/peent2-ruben/Colorclicker/src

Class that calls the addtoShape and deletefromShape can be found here:
https://github.com/Rubenkl/peent-daanruben/blob/peent2-ruben/Colorclicker/src/DrawingPanel.java

Comment: As I see it, the variable is set correctly to `listModel.size() - 1`. Are you sure your data is correct and that you are printing the right values? I can't see anything wrong with the code. For example, are you sure you are sending the same MyShape object to the methods addShapeToList and deleteFromList?

Comment: Looks like your listModel object has only 1 element in its list. And as we know list starts from 0 and ends at 1 if it has only one member. So listModel.size()-1 = 0. 
When you say `shape.setRightIdent(listModel.size()-1)` in your addToShapeList(MyShape shape) method. It should be zero. 
What value are you expecting??

Comment: @OlaviMustanoja It should send the same MyShape object to deleteFromList, as there is just one shape created.

That's exactly why I did setRightIdent(ListModel.Size()-1), because it should set it to the first position.

What I basically try to achieve is that there are 2 lists filled with shapes: one for painting and the other for displaying what kind of shape there are in the field (just like layers in photoshop)

Comment: I'll try out your code later today, but the bottomline is that the shapes sent to the two methods are not the same. Try working with that assumption for now :)

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. You never set the right ident on a newly created shape in *DrawingPanel.java*. Here's my fix for you:

```
    switch(command) {
                case "Rectangle":
                    shape = new MyRectangle(start.x, start.y, end.x, end.y);
                    shape.setRightIdent(index); // here
                    if (newww) {
                        rightPanel.addToShapeList(shape);
                        shapesList.add(shape);
                    } else {
                        shape.getRightIdent());
                        shapesList.set(index, shape);
                    }
                    break;
                case "Line":
                    shape = new MyLine(start.x, start.y, end.x, end.y);
                    shape.setRightIdent(index); // here
                    if (newww) {
                        rightPanel.addToShapeList(shape);
                        shapesList.add(shape);
                    } else {
                        shapesList.set(index, shape);
                    }

                    break;
                case "Ellipse":
                    shape = new MyEllipse(start.x, start.y, end.x, end.y);
                    shape.setRightIdent(index); // here
                    if (newww) {
                        rightPanel.addToShapeList(shape);
                        shapesList.add(shape);
                    } else {
                        shapesList.set(index, shape);
                    }
                    break;
```

Comment: It's not the index you need to set though. Because it will be the index number of the list of the rightPanel list.